# PostgreSQL assign sequence number from SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to restart sequence with max+1 of certain table.

```
SELECT max(id)+1 
    INTO testVal
FROM project;

ALTER SEQUENCE project_id_seq RESTART testVal;
```

This gives syntax error at testVal. Can someone please explain me what is a problem, propose alternative solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for sequences you should be using setval

`SELECT SETVAL('project_id_seq', (SELECT max(id)+1 FROM project))`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html

Comment: Oh, thats way cleaner, tested and seems to be working properly. Thank you. BTW would you know why my solution was not working? Just to take a lesson from it.

Comment: Your ALTER SEQUENCE referred only to the table name, however it would require a subquery to select that column and I do not believe you could do that - also `SELECT [columns] INTO [tablename]` creates a table with that data inside but since you did not give `max(id)+1 ` an alias it would default a name to something like `?column?`

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. Thanks